# XML file needed for Channable

Tags: xml

Can someone help us with getting a XML file from our products so we can upload this file into Channable?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! To help the community provide an answer, could you please share what product data you want in your export feed? Do you need the file to be downloadable or accessible externally to an API? While we might not be familiar with Channable, if you know what data is needed we can probably assist!

Comment: Hi Cherry, thank you! the XML file should contain all available attributes/data of all our products. Think, color, size, title, description, shipping costs, age group, gender, shipping info, availability. All that kind of stuff. 

Then I need a link from of XML file that I can give to Channable so that all the data can be imported there via that link. 

Hopefully that will provide a little more clarity, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your best bet is to create a [Twig template](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/twig-primer.html), say `myxml.twig`, in your Craft `templates` folder that pulls the exact data you want from your Craft installation and outputs it as XML in the exact format that you want or Channable requires.

Then, you'll be able to load `mysite.com/myxml` in a browser to see your XML file and that's what you can point Channable to, so it can consume it.

Comment: also - if you want to set a custom URL for this template, you can add an entry to the routes config file to make it mysite.com/whatever/youwant

Comment: Hi Brad, thank you for your reply!

Is this something you can help me with? I, unfortunately, don't have any knowledge regarding this topic.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @BeauHendriks you'll likely need a developer to help you with this. Craft sites are 100% custom-built, so I can't give you the exact steps. Someone will need to code this based on your site's information architecture and your business needs.